# Sidebar attached to the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu and sidebar with sticky positions
My task is to keep the menu and sidebar locked at the top of the screen when scrolling
For the menu, I applied the sticky-top bootstrap class
But the sidebar when using this class does not take into account the menu and runs over it
I can't write to js, so I have to ask for help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

first, create div which you want to set sticky with class sticky then write to your style tag this:

```
div.sticky {
   position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0; }
```

Comment: I already did it, the problem is that the sidebar is below the menu and should not overlap with the menu, I just can't set the margin because I make a rubber layout. ( The menu has a sticky position )

Comment: can you screenshot your result?